# Where do I find the most up-to-date Android versions of SDK and Build Tools?

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I'm enrolled in Udacity's Android Basics Nanodegree, and throughout the course we are told to update the following to the most current versions:
compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion
targetSdkVersion

But searching for the current versions doesn't seem to give me an answer. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools and https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms

Comment: Thank you so much!